# Dynamic if loop (Business Logic)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a user input as a tuple list which shows the minimum and maximum profit with the percentage profit within that range, as the following tuple list shows:

```
args_tuple = (("min1" , 0), ("max1", 10000) , ("percentage1", 0.1),
              ("min2" , 10000) , ("max2", 50000), ("percentage2", 0.05) ,
              ("min3" , 50000), ("max3",100000), ("percentage3",0.1) ,
              ("min4" , 100000), ("max4",None), ("percentage4",0.05))
```

I made a simple function to calculate the profit according to that percentage as the following code shows:

```
def profitCalculator(summed, args_tuple):
    profit = 0

    args_tuple = dict(args_tuple)

    if args_tuple['min1'] <= summed < args_tuple['max1']:
        profit += (summed * args_tuple['percentage1'])
    elif args_tuple['min2'] <= summed < args_tuple['max2']:
        profit += (args_tuple['min2'] * args_tuple['percentage1'])
        summed -= args_tuple['min2']
        profit += (summed * args_tuple['percentage2'])
    elif args_tuple['min3'] <= summed < args_tuple['max3']:
        profit += (args_tuple['min2'] * args_tuple['percentage1'])
        profit += ((args_tuple['min3'] - args_tuple['min2']) *  args_tuple['percentage2'])
        summed -= args_tuple['min3']
        profit += (summed * args_tuple['percentage3'])
    elif summed >= args_tuple['min4']:
        profit += (args_tuple['min2'] * args_tuple['percentage1'])
        profit += ((args_tuple['min3'] - args_tuple['min2']) * args_tuple['percentage2'])
        profit += ((args_tuple['min3']) * args_tuple['percentage3'])
        summed -= args_tuple['min4']
        profit += (summed * args_tuple['percentage4'])
    return profit
```

What I need now is, instead of expanding if statements, I just need a dynamic while loop in case the user adds `("min5..." , 150000), ("max5...", 200000) , ("percentage5...", 0.1)`, with the same profit calculations showed in my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your algorithm if you change the representation of the data.
For example, instead of using nested tuples you can use the nested list like this.

```
args = [[0,10000,0.1],[10000,50000,0.05]]
```

where the first element in the inner list represents a minimum, second maximum and third percentage.

then you can easily write a for loop

```
for minimum, maximum, profit in (args):
  print(minimum, maximum, profit)
```

then use your business logic to compute profit

---

and if you need the index

```
for index,(minimum, maximum, profit) in enumerate(args):
  print(index,minimum, maximum, profit)
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, I implemented it according to this logic as an answer too down here :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your business logic code will as below

```
def profitCalculator(summed, args_tuple):
    counter = 1
    profit = 0
    args_tuple = dict(args_tuple)
    while args_tuple.has_key("min" + str(counter)):
        if True:
            for i in range(1, counter):
                iplus = i + 1
                if iplus % 2 == 0:
                    profit += (args_tuple['min' + str(iplus)] * args_tuple['percentage' + str(i)])
                if i - 2 == 0:
                    profit += ((args_tuple['min' + str(iplus)]) * args_tuple['percentage' + str(i)])
                if i == counter - 1:
                    summed -= args_tuple['min' + str(counter)]
            profit += (summed * args_tuple['percentage' + str(counter)])
        counter = counter + 1
    return profit
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, here is a short implementation:

```
args = [[0,10000,0.1],[10000,50000,0.05],[50000,100000,0.1],[100000,200000,0.05]]
def monthlyProfitCalc(summed, args):
    temp = 0
    profit = []
    for index, (minimum, maximum, profitpercent) in enumerate(args):
        if minimum <= summed < maximum:
            profit = [abs(args[x][0] - args[x+1][0])*args[x][2] for x in range(index)]
            temp = sum(temp + i for i in [abs(args[x][0] - args[x+1][0]) for x in range(index)])
            summed -= temp
            profit.append(summed * profitpercent)
    return sum(profit)
```